# what is the meaning of subclass::superclass in c++

Tags: c++

Consider the following code

```
class abc
{
};

class def: public abc 
{
};

void main()
{
    abc a1;
    def a2;
    def::abc a3;
}
```

What is meant by `def::abc` here; is `abc` a member of `def`?
Are `a3` and `a1` similar?

Comment: `def::abc` is the same as `abc`. It's redundant. See also: [injected-class-name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name)

Comment: Read a good [C++ programming book](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html), then see [some C++ reference website](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp), and perhaps [this draft C++11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)

Comment: Thank you. Got it. Just wanted to confirm this. 

Comment: if you prefer experimenting over rtfm you could check `std::is_same_v<abc,def::abc>` to see that they are the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**def::abc a3;** is same as **abc a1;**. You can check order of instantiation as below :

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
   public:
      Base()
      {   
         std::cout << "Base\n";
      }
};

class Derived: public Base
{
   public:
      Derived()
      {   
          std::cout << "Derived\n";
      }
  };

  int main()
  {
      std::cout << "Instantiating Base\n";
      Base cBase;

      std::cout << "Instantiating Derived\n";
      Derived cDerived;

      std::cout << "Instantiating Derived::Base\n";
      Derived::Base cBDerived;

     return 0;
  }
```

Output is :

> ```
> Instantiating Base
> Base
> Instantiating Derived
> Base
> Derived
> Instantiating Derived::Base
> Base
> ```

Comment: Glad it helped! You can also mark the answer useful :-)